# How to get data out of citrix

Tags: automation, citrix

Here's what I want to be able to do:

Run a program on my local computer which logs in to a citrix server (using citrix receiver or doing so in a similar way), on the server in the citrix session open a web browser, load a website, and then bring the html of that site back out of the citrix session and onto my local computer. Bascially I want to get data out of a citrix remote session.

How can I do this programmatically?

I'm fine with whatever programming language/modality you are comfortable in answering the question using.

I've looked a little into the citrix apis but while I find some things about logging in and even sending keystrokes and mouse clicks I found nothing about obtaining data. I could just log in and then use a program like wireshark to get the information, but I'm guessing it's all encrypted (plus then I wouldn't be doing my task all programmatically). I know of at least one open source program which seems to be able to replace a citrix reciever/client (openthinclient.org) but before I got digging through all its source code to try to answer my question I thought I'd ask here in case someone had an easier answer.

Comment: No ideas from anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to automate the task, is having the program act as a citrix client necessary?

I assume you don't have install privileges inside your citrix session, so are unable to install one of the many automation tools available (such as http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)?

Given the above...

If you have/allow java on your local machine, have a look at http://www.sikuli.org/

The main difference between this and other automation tools I've come across is that Sikuli uses the image on screen to navigate the gui, rather than grabbing calls to the widgets (which wont work in a citrix session).

So, assuming you can take a screenshot of your citrix session, it could be useful to you.